# comparing values for setting bgcolor of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am comparing two values set bij data attributes (res and ref) in a div and based on that I want to set the bgcolor of the div. Somehow it does not work. No bgcolor set as a result.

---

Html

```
<div id="grid">
  <div class="item blue" data-kpi="one" data-res="8" data-ref="4" ></div>
  <div class="item yellow" data-kpi="two" data-res="4" data-ref="7" data-groups='["all", "numbers", "green", "square"]'>  </div> 
  <div class="item blue" data-kpi="three" data-res="8" data-ref="13"></div>
</div>
```

---

jQuery

```
$('#grid div.item[data-res][data-ref]').each(function(index){
    var res = $(this).data('res');
    var ref = $(this).data('ref');

   if(res > ref)
   {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
   }  
  else if(ref > res)
   {
   $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
   }
  else 
   { 
   $(this).css('background-color', 'black');  
   }

});
```

Comment: works fine here:: http://jsfiddle.net/U3Dpn/

Comment: btw, did you wrap it in $(document).ready(function() { ... });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse the values to int using `parseInt()` before comparing them.

```
var res = parseInt($(this).data('res'));
var ref = parseInt($(this).data('ref'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put some data in the divs, then you will the get the result.

**HTML**

```
  <div id="grid">
     <div class="item blue" data-kpi="one" data-res="8" data-ref="4" >Hai</div>
     <div class="item yellow" data-kpi="two" data-res="4" data-ref="7" data-groups='["all",  "numbers", "green", "square"]'>All</div> 
     <div class="item blue" data-kpi="three" data-res="8" data-ref="13">the Best</div>
 </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
  $('#grid div.item[data-res][data-ref]').each(function(index) {
          var res = parseInt($(this).data('res'));
          var ref = parseInt$(this).data('ref'));

      if(res > ref) {
           $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
       } 
      else if(ref > res) {
           $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
      }
      else  { 
          $(this).css('background-color', 'black');  
      }

   })
```

Now you check it.